# div ignoring explicitly set width

Tags: html, width

I've got a container that has a contact form in it.. the form is ignoring my width of 140px and somehow computing itself out to 300px. no idea where it's coming from.

HTML:

```html
<div id="main" role="main">
        <div id="mail"> 
            <form id="signup" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get"> 
                <fieldset>
                    <span id="response">
                        <? require_once('php/store-address.php'); if($_GET['submit']){ echo storeAddress(); } ?>
                    </span>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" /> 
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn" value="Go" />             
                </fieldset> 
            </form> 
        </div> 
    </div>
```

CSS:

```css
#main {
    width:300px;
    height:110px;
    padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:50px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-170px;
    background-color: #f0f3f8;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#f0f3f8), to(#a9a9ad));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 100% 90deg, #a9a9ad, #f0f3f8);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#f0f3f8, #a9a9ad);
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    //text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    //border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

////////CONTACT FORM

#mail {
    width:140px;
    height:95px;
    float:right;
    display:block;
    /*background: #c9d0de; border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #444;*/
}
#response {
    width:140px;
    height:25px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    display:block;
    font-style:italic;
}
input {
    width: 124px;
    height: 9px;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0; 
    background: #5E768D;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #546A7F 0%, #5E768D 20%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#546A7F), color-stop(20%,#5E768D));
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #334f71;
    outline:none;
}
    input::-webkit-input-placeholder  {
        color: #a1b2c3; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #38506b;  
    }
    input:-moz-placeholder {
        color: #a1b2c3; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #38506b; 
    }
    
input:focus, textarea:focus {
    background: #728eaa;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #668099 0%, #728eaa 20%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#668099), color-stop(20%,#728eaa));
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 40px;
    height: 25px;
    padding:5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #999;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #999;
    border: 1px solid #556f8c;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #718DA9 0%, #415D79 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#718DA9), color-stop(100%,#415D79));
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/7Hs2r/1/)

Comment: The form or the div is set to 140px?

Comment: The div with id="main" has a width set to 300px in css. This might be the one you need to change

Comment: @Bryce: move that to an answer so you can get credit. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have comments with //. Only multi-line comments work with css. You'll have to remove this comment:

```
////////CONTACT FORM
```

The rest of your styles should work after you remove that.

Comment: Totally didn't even notice that in the CSS. +1 from me too!